# How return value from promise

Tags: javascript, promise

How can I return value from promise. I want compare value of promise with my limit balance. But I can't return my result in my condition.

```
if (getBalanceByAddress(....) > 228) {
    console.log('ALL ok')
} else {
    console.log('insufficient funds')
}

getBalanceByAddress(addressFrom) {
    var _this = this;
    return _this.web3.eth.getBalance(addressFrom).then(function(result) {
        return result;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hint: when `getBalanceByAddress` returns, the call is still in progress, so the result is not available yet. You have to append result handling at the end of the promise chain.

Comment: How about trying a different approach :)
       
     getBalanceByAddress(....).then((result)=>{
        if ( result > 228) {
            console.log('ALL ok')
        } else {
            console.log('insufficient funds')
        }
        })
        getBalanceByAddress(addressFrom) {
            var _this = this;
            return _this.web3.eth.getBalance(addressFrom)
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to await it:

```
 (async function(){ 
  if( await getBalanceByAddress() > 228){
   console.log('ALL ok');
  } else {
   console.log('insufficient funds');
  }
 })()
```

Comment: Even though attached duplicate link has answered it, I still liked this simple solution (no scrolling) +1. You still need to let OP know the browser support of this solution though!